# How do you downcast to byte[]?

Tags: f#

```
    let f (o:obj option) = 
        o
        |> Option.bind(
            function 
                | :? byte[] as b -> Some b 
                | _ -> None)
```

but that doesn't compile

the following could fail at run-time instead of cast only if it is the right type already so that doesn't match the behavior I desire

`let f (o:obj option) = o |> Option.map(fun b -> b :?> byte[])`

how do you test cast an `obj` down to `byte[]` ?

Comment: If you enclose ``byte[]`` with parens it will compile.